# How can I delay running a function until after jQuery get() has finished

Tags: jquery

I'm using this piece of code inside of a for loop to append some content to a div:

```
$.get("./" + i + "/block.html", function(data){ 
    $(data).appendTo("#id");
});
```

After that, I'm using this piece of code to make the added content clickable, there's a `.person` div inside every `block.html`:

```
$(".person").click(function () { 
    $(this).toggleClass("large");
});
```

This second piece of code has no effect because the first piece runs asynchronously. So the content hasn't been appended yet by the time it runs. How can I delay it until it has been?

Comment: Btw another potential problem is that the data isn't necessarily appended in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is with a counter and if all data is loaded add it, this also ensures the data is added in the right order. The keyword `let` (instead of `var`) is very important, otherwise you have to use closures to capture the current value of `i`.

```
function addData(n) {
    let count = 0, content = []
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        $.get("./" + i + "/block.html", function(data) { 
            content[i] = data // using var i would be n here
            if (++count == n) {
                for (let j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    $(content[j]).appendTo("#id")
                $(".person").click(function () { 
                    $(this).toggleClass("large")
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a simpler solution I found.

You can run

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

at the start to make the `get()` functions run synchronously. If you need them to run asynchronously for another part of the page, just run

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true});
```

to switch back to asynchronous mode afterward.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5641995/7752942)

Comment: The reason I didn't mention that is: As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done(). But maybe I didn't understand this correctly and it is still usable if you don't use the jqXHR object? I don't know. Anyway the main difference is that this doesn't make the requests in parallel but sequential.